# Get fields names from a recordset in an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, vba, function, recordset

I wrote a function to get fields names from an adodb recordset into an array (in VBA) and it works fine.

Now I'm trying to transfer the code into vb.net but I'm stuck on this function:

This is the VBA working code:

```
Public Function NomiCampi(MyRs As ADODB.Recordset, ByRef Dest())
Dim Flds, i%
Set Flds = MyRs.Fields
ReDim Dest(Flds.Count - 1)
For i = 0 To Flds.Count - 1
    Dest(i) = Flds(i).Name
Next i
End Function
```

I use it this way (where rs is a recordset and Campi is an array of strings):

```
Call NomiCampi(rs, Campi)
```

I made several attempts in vb.net but nothing worked. This is the actual code (that doesn't work):

```
Public Function NomiCampi(ByVal MyRs As ADODB.Recordset) As String()
    Dim Matrice(), Flds, i%
    Flds = MyRs.Fields
    ReDim Matrice(Flds.Count - 1)
    For i = 0 To Flds.Count - 1
        Matrice(i) = CStr(Flds(i).Name)
    Next i
    NomiCampi = Matrice
    Stop
End Function
```

Where do I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, change your function so it actually returns something:

```
Public Function NomiCampi(ByVal MyRs As ADODB.Recordset) As String()
    Dim Matrice As String()
    Dim Flds As ADODB.Fields
    Dim i As Integer
    Flds = MyRs.Fields
    ReDim Matrice(Flds.Count - 1)
    For i = 0 To Flds.Count - 1
        Matrice(i) = CStr(Flds(i).Name)
    Next i
    Return Matrice
End Function
```

Then call with:

```
Dim Campi As String() = NomiCampi(rs)
```

Or, if you have already declared `Campi`:

```
Campi = NomiCampi(rs)
```